# Troubleshooting SSL/TLS Error When Installing Cypress in Corporate Environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, cypress, tls1.2

I was trying to install Cypress in my corporate environment using npm, but I encountered an SSL/TLS error. I suspect it might be related to our corporate proxy settings

**Error Message**:
When I run `npm install cypress --save-dev`, I receive the following error:

`npm ERR! code ERR_SSL_TLSV1_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME npm ERR! errno ERR_SSL_TLSV1_UNRECOGNIZED_NAME npm ERR! request to https://proxy.example.net/cypress failed, reason: D04D0000:error:0A000458:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:tlsv1 unrecognized name:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\rec_layer_s3.c:1586:SSL alert number 112`

Environment:

- Operating System: Windows
- Node.js and npm versions: Latest

I've tried several troubleshooting steps, including configuring npm and environment variables for proxy settings, but none resolved the issue. I've also consulted related discussions on Stack Overflow and other forums, as well as the Cypress documentation, without success.

Proxy Configuration Attempts:

- `npm config set proxy http://proxy.example.net:70`
- `npm config set https-proxy http://proxy.example.net:70`
- Environment variable settings for HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY

Additional Steps:
Consulted our corporate networking team
Temporarily disabled strict SSL settings in npm (with caution) Despite these efforts, the SSL/TLS certificate issue persists.

I'm looking for advanced troubleshooting techniques or insights into potential causes that might not be addressed by standard procedures.

Note: Specific network details have been altered for security and privacy.